# Cannot Resolve Symbol Error When Calling SavingChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

All,

I am working from the following [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  Yet I am getting: "Cannot resolve symbol SavingChanges"

The call in question is:

```
contextProxy.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(context_SavingChanges);
```

contextProxy is of type: **public class ReportingContext : DbContext** which is my context class that handles all EF data models, etc. So if the issue is that DBContext does not inherit from whatever SavingChanges needs (ObjectContext?) how can I fix?

**My implementation**

```
public class ReportingProxy
{

    // Define the object context to be provided. 
    private ReportingContext contextProxy = new ReportingContext();

    public ReportingProxy()
    {
        // When the object is initialized, register the  
        // handler for the SavingChanges event.
        contextProxy.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(context_SavingChanges);
    }

    // Method that provides an object context. 
    public ReportingContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return contextProxy;
        }
    }

    // SavingChanges event handler. 
    private void context_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newClubIdToUpdate = 0;

        // Ensure that we are passed an ObjectContext
        ObjectContext context = sender as ObjectContext;
        if (context != null)
        {

            // Validate the state of each entity in the context before SaveChanges can succeed. 
            foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
                context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                    EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted))
            {

                if (SecurityHelper.IsValidNewClubTableName(entry.EntitySet.Name)) 
                {
                    if (!entry.IsRelationship && (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof (NewClub)))
                    {
                        var nc = entry.Entity as NewClub;
                        newClubIdToUpdate = (nc != null ? nc.Id : 0);
                    }

                    if (!entry.IsRelationship && (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof (NewClubProspect)))
                    {
                        var ncp = entry.Entity as NewClubProspect;
                        newClubIdToUpdate = (ncp != null ? ncp.NewClubId : 0);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Update the NewClub.LastActivityDate column
            if (newClubIdToUpdate > 0)
            {
                string q = @"UPDATE NewClub SET LastActivityDate='" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Id=" + newClubIdToUpdate;


                using (var cxt = new ReportingContext())
                {
                    var result = cxt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(q);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `SavingChanges` event on `DbContext`. It is only on `ObjectContext`, which is what the MSDN article you linked to was about.

[Here's an article](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/12/ef-code-first-dbcontext-savingchanges/) on how you can get to it from the `DbContext` though.

To avoid link rot, here is the example modified for your scenario:

```
using (var contextProxy = new ReportingContext())
{
    var objCtx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)contextProxy ).ObjectContext;

    objCtx.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(context_SavingChanges);
}
```